# Getting this error when added RxBinding

Tags: rx-java, rx-android

I am getting this error when added RxBinding

```
"Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14 cannot be smaller than version 15 declared in library /app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.jakewharton.rxbinding/rxbinding/0.1.0/AndroidManifest.xml Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.jakewharton.rxbinding" to force usage"
```

Should follow suggestion or upgrade my sdk:minSdkVersion to 15 or is there any better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that upgrade sdk:minSdkVersion to 15 is a preferable solution.

1. It is safer (you don't know are there any features of 15 used in RxBinding)
2. It is simpler (you don't need to analyze RxBinding or remove RxBinding from your code)
3. According to [Android Dashboard](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) there are less than 0.1% users with Skd 14

Comment: Thanks for the info, will update my sdk:minSdkVersion.